# What's the correct way to run a monthly simulation from a table data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have different areas and want to see month by month how their expenses progress.

Let me give you an example:

**Data:**

```
+-------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| Area  | Fix-cost | Per-person-cost | people |
+-------+----------+-----------------+--------+
| Area1 |   100000 |             400 |     10 |
| Area2 |   100000 |             400 |     10 |
| Area3 |   100000 |             400 |     10 |
| Area4 |   100000 |             400 |     10 |
| Area5 |   100000 |             400 |     10 |
| Area6 |        0 |             450 |     2  |
+-------+----------+-----------------+--------+
```

I want to simulate a year of cost for each Area

Let's say the formula for each area is something like `(Fix-cost + cost-per-person * people)`

What would be the correct way to retrieve the data from the table to obtain something like this?

```
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|             | 01/01/17 | 02/01/17 | 03/01/17 | 04/01/17 |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| Area1       |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |
| Area2       |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |
| Area3       |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |
| Area4       |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |
| Area5       |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |   104000 |
| Area6       |      900 |      900 |      900 |      900 |
| Total       |   520900 |   520900 |   520900 |   520900 |
| Accumulated |   520900 |  1041800 |  1562700 |  2083600 |
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I am trying to avoid having to reference each cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I'd have a flat table with the first row being column titles of "Date", "Area", "Fix Cost", "Cost Per Person", "People"

Fill that in, then highlight the entire set of data including the column titles and then, within the Insert ribbon, click "Insert Table"

Now, in that title row, in the cell to the right of "People", add "Cost". The formatting should suddenly shift to include your new column.

The really cool thing about tables, besides being able to format them nicely, is that you can refer to other cells using the column title name.

So if you're using Excel 2010 or later, in the cell below "Cost", add a formula of `=[@Fix Cost]+[@Cost Per Person]*[@People]`

Like magic, the entire column should fill in!

If your cursor/selection is within the table, you should see a "table design" ribbon. Click into it and, on the left in the ribbon, give your table a friendly name. (No spaces allowed in the name.)

Then, go to the Insert ribbon and create a pivot table in a new sheet. If you've never done it before, it will seem weird, but you did save a backup before messing with this, right? Right?

In the field list that appears when you create a pivot table, drag the Area to the row headers, the Date to the column headers, the Cost into the Data, and then click on "Count of Cost" to change it to sum instead.

That should get you most of the way there. I've no idea what that "Accumulate" row is in your question.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the second table has to be right beside the first one. I've been googling a bit and it seems that you can't reference a specific column of a table from somewhere in the book.

Comment: @FedericoNafria - second table?  I'm not sure what you mean unless you meant to say "second column".

Comment: If your table's name is "Table1" then you can reference an entire column with Table1[ColumnName] anywhere in the workbook, though the "@" sign (that's shorthand for Table1[[#ThisRow],[ColumnName]]) won't work outside of the table because the context won't make sense. That said, if you want a value per row in the table, it makes to add a column right there in the table because that way any time you add a new row the column formula is automatically extended into that row as well.

Comment: @FedericoNafria - If this has answered your question, would you please mark it as such?